# Bootstrap modals - Close first by clicking second

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

Good day. I have two instances of bootstrap 3 modals on the page.
For example, first: is "Authorization" modal, and second: is "Forgot password" modal, which calls by link in first modal. The second modal has reverse link for first too. Here is the code (Authorization):

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modal-authorization" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog authorization" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-inner authorization">
                <div class="modal-inner__title">
                    Authorization
                </div>
                <form action="">
                    <input class="modal-inner__input" type="text" placeholder="Login" required>
                    <input class="modal-inner__input" type="password" placeholder="Password" required>
                    <button class="btn btn-vote" type="submit">Sign In</button>
                </form>
                <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-restore">
                    Forgot Password?
                </a>
                <a class="modal-close" data-dismiss="modal">X
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And second modal, "Forgot Password":

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modal-restore" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog restore" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-inner authorization">
                <div class="modal-inner__title">
                    Forgot Password?
                </div>
                <form action="">
                    <input class="modal-inner__input" type="email" placeholder="Enter your E-mail" required>
                    <button class="btn btn-vote" type="submit">Get new Password</button>
                </form>
                <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-authorization">
                  Go to Authorization
                </a>
                <a class="modal-close" data-dismiss="modal">
                    X
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, I have the link with `data-target="#modal-restore"` which calls the second modal from first and `data-target="#modal-authorization"` which calls the first modal from second.

I need it so that when I open the second or the first window from another, another shall be closed. I can't find the solution to my problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only add the `data-dismiss="modal"` to the link that open the second modal

```
<a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-authorization" data-dismiss="modal">
    Go to Authorization
</a>
```

Comment: Thank you! That's what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

Remove data-dismiss attribute from close buttons. Close the modal pop up using the pop up method call via click event.

```
    function close(id) {
      $('#id').modal("hide")
    }
```